# JavaScript Conditional Statement Not Working

Tags: javascript, math, conditional-statements

What's wrong with this JavaScript?

```
var numPackages == 0;

if (coffeeProducts <= 12) {
  numPackages == 1;
} else if (coffeeProducts % 12 == 0) {
  numPackages == coffeeProducts/12;
} else {
  numPackages == (coffeeProducts/12) + 1;
}
```

Basically, it needs to calculate the number of boxes/packages necessary to ship an amount of items (12 per box). Is there a better way to do this, perhaps using round()?

Comment: The problem is that you're confusing assignments with conditionals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the others explained your mistake with the comparing operator `==` and the assigning operator `=`.

The shortest way to solve it would be

```
var numPackages = Math.ceil( coffeeProducts / 12 );
```

Answer (score 5):

`==` is condition.

`=` is assignment.

The better way is to use `Math.ceil()` to round to next integer.

So:

```
var numPackages = Math.ceil(coffeeProducts/12);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make each statement look like this:

```
if (coffeeProducts <= 12) {
    numPackages = 1; // just "=", not "=="
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Single equals (=) for assignment: **x = 10**

Double equals (==) for comparison: **if (x == 10)**

Triple equals for special cases where *type* is important as well as the value.

Change your two **numPackages** lines to a single equals and you're good to go :)